# Can't launch edge browser from Jenkins build job but same is working on from eclipse

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver, jenkins

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Microsoft Edge failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from msedge location C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe is no longer running, so msedgedriver is assuming that msedge has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'HJNZL000593', ip: '192.168.1.15', os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '18.0.2.1'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF665DDDB12+60274]
    Microsoft::Applications::Events::EventProperty::~EventProperty [0x00007FF665D6E772+818882]
```

Above error showed up when job executed from Jenkins.

I tried using chrome browser and its working. I am expecting same works for edge browser also.

Comment: Running Jenkins as a standalone application resolved my issue.